# how to find matching objects only in array using mongoTemplate in spring

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

currently i am using mongoDB in spring as mongoTemplate . i have 2 questions
1.How to execute raw queries in mongoTemplate
2.how to find matching objects only in array using mongoTemplate in single document

after sorting by createDate this is document i am getting.here movies array contains objects.i want to get only matched objects from this sorted document.not from entire collection
    example:

```
{
    "category": "movies",
    "movies": [
        {
          "name": "HarryPotter",
          "language": "english"
        },
        {
          "name": "conjuring",
          "language": "english"
        },
        {
            "name": "Fana",
            "language": "hindi"
        }
    ],
   "createDate" : ISODate("2016-11-4T14:57:12.750+0000")
}

if movies.language is english in query 
excepted OutPut:
{
    "category": "movies",
    "movies": [
        {
            "name": "HarryPotter",
            "language": "english"
        },{
            "name": "conjuring",
            "language": "english"
        }
    ]
}
```